# Ввести кириллицу в data.frame

Tags: r, rstudio

Ввожу, RStudio

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', 'russian');
tracking_row <- data.frame(date = Sys.time(), select_word = "тест")
```

Получаю

```
> tracking_row
                 date select_word
1 2016-09-06 13:14:03        òåñò
```

Спасибо за помощь

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251
```

Comment: Не плохо бы показать `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Это в Rstudio или R-cmd?

Comment: Так же возможно вот этот [вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900668/r-wrong-encoding-in-rstudio-console-but-ok-in-r-gui-and-ggplot2)  поможет

Comment: Добавил деталей